# Getting distinct rows from a table using combination of two columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
Status   Time          Handel  Title

---------      ------------     ------       ------------- 
CREATED   2009-10-16 03:37:38+01   902D8   Mozilla Firefox
ACTIVATED 2009-10-16 03:37:38+01  902D8  -?-
ACTIVATED 2009-10-16 03:37:41+01  902D8  -?-
ACTIVATED 2009-10-16 03:37:41+01  E030E  Windows Live Messenger
DESTROYED 2009-10-16 03:37:42+01  E030E  Windows Live Messenger
ACTIVATED 2009-10-16 03:37:42+01  902D8  -?-
DESTROYED 2009-10-16 03:37:53+01  902D8  -?-
```

I want distinct values on the basis of only "handel column" and "Title column". For example, Handel: 902D8 and Title: -?- should only appear once

The result of query on above data  should be

```
Status   Time             Handel  Title
---------    ------------          ------  ------------- 
CREATED   2009-10-16 03:37:38+01   902D8   Mozilla Firefox
ACTIVATED 2009-10-16 03:37:38+01  902D8  -?-
ACTIVATED 2009-10-16 03:37:41+01  E030E  Windows Live Messenger
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: Which `Status` and `Time` values do you need?

Comment: as per your example you given above you need time of the 1st similar data found i.e. (2009-10-16 03:37:38+01) and ot (2009-10-16 03:37:41+01).
Please use 1st query of the answer given by me below.

Comment: status and time do not matter, all i want is that: handel having same title become distinct. e.g (902D8 and -?- should appear only once) thanks.

Comment: thanks Salil, but i dont have ID coulmn. only have Status,Time,Handel and Title columns

Comment: If the other columns don't matter, why not use `SELECT DISTINCT Handel, Titel`? Any reason you need the other two columns?

Comment: i need all columns in the results, but the criteria for Distinct is only to be based on HANDEL and TITLE

Comment: which primary key present in your table.

Comment: @ Salil - no primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table where id in (select min(id) from table group by handle, title)
```

OR

```
select * from table where id in (select max(id) from table group by handle, title)
```

Comment: A more efficent solution can be obtained with OLAP functions (also known as analytic functions) if the environment support them (DB2 and Oracle does), but judging from the tags we are talking about ms-access so your answer is the best possible I think.

Comment: @ Salil - I added the primary key and it worked with that, though very slow in execution but worked for me. Thanks alot.

Comment: @Andrea Polci: the MS-ACCESS tag can mean that the front end is Access and the back end datastore is just about any database engine in existence, so your mention of the OLAP functions is potentially helpful, if not to this particular questioner, possibly to someone coming on the question later.